# Shortcut Key Assigned To A Link Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The shortcut key assigned to a picture doesn't work in the following code. I have assigned Alt+2 as the shortcut for the link through a Javascript function(). But somehow, the shortcut doesn't work.

```
         <a href="cochin.jpg" onkeypress="return runScript(event)" 
         runat="server" id="HyLnk">ClickMe!!
         </a>

         <script type="text/javascript">
            function runScript(e) {

              if (e.keyCode == 50) {
                _doPostBack('<%=HyLnk.id%>', "");
                return true;
               }
              else {

                return false;
               }
            }

          </script>
```

Comment: Do alert(e.keyCode); and check if the value is coming correctly

Comment: @BaN3 Nothing gets displayed. Which means that no javascript function is being fired.

Answer (score 0):

```
shortcut.add("Alt+2",function() {
    _doPostBack('<%=HyLnk.id%>', "");
});
```

Try out this Replace Your function block with this, You wont need the onkeypress for this either

Comment: Error Message: Error 1 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) d:\ADO_NETprojects\GetValueFromCsharp_to_Aspx\Default.aspx 12